# How to split numbers into different parts

Tags: excel

I have been trying to find a way to split numbers in excel just by using formula.

The aim was to use the list below

```
Pens:
Black:30
Blue:20
Red:47
Green:17
Total:114
```

To split into different boxes the number of boxes is determined by how many pens can fit in a box in this case the max is 22.

The formula for the boxes calculation :

```
`=114 / 22 = 5.18`
```

which is rounded up into 6 boxes needed

Is there any formula which is capable of splitting the numbers into the boxes, the colour can be mixed doesn't have to be one colour only.

Note: the boxes don't have to be filled to the max it would be much better if it can be split nicely into the 6 boxes.

```
The expected output: when splitting nicely
Pen:
Black : 19 11 0 0 0 0
Blue:   0 8 12 0 0 0 
Red:    0 0 7 19 19 2
Green:  0 0 0 0 0 17
Total:  19 19 19 19 19 19
```

Comment: In your case what is the expected output and what formula you used to calculate it manually? please put that in the question as well

Comment: you already have a working formula to calculate the boxes. what is your exact question. and please explain what you mean by 'split nicely'

Answer (score 1):

Excel is all about numbers and as such it is always best to store numbers only in cells. Like this you can add, substract, multiply, and divide more easily. Hence, your list which seems to be currently something like this:

[image]

Should rather be something like this:

[image]

To accomplish this you could split column `A` into two columns using `Text to Columns` function in the `Data` tab and then split on `:`.

Alternatively, you can also keep everything as is and merely store the number values in each cell. Then you can change the number format for each cell to show what ever text you want like this:

[image]

Note, that only the number `17` is stored in the cell (as is visible from the formula bar). Yet, the number format for this cell ensures that it is shown as `Green:17`.

If you don't care about any of the above and just want a quick solution to all the text stored in column a then you can use the following array-formula:

```
{=ROUNDUP(SUM(VALUE(MID(A2:A5,FIND(":",A2:A5)+1,LEN(A2:A5))))/22,0)}
```

Note the curved brackets around the formula which indicates an array formula. You'll have to enter the formula without the curved brackets and the press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Return`. Excel will automatically place the curved brackets around and thereby confirm that this is an array formula:

[image]

Comment: is there any formula to split the numbers into different cells? e.g 30 is split into 19 and 11 like the above.

Comment: The problem with your request is that you need as many formulas in as many cells as the input requires. So, in your case you need 6 columns to the right because `114 / 22 = 6` (when rounded up). But if your input requires 10 boxes and thus 10 columns then your solution would have to adjust itself. So, you need to write formulas into the adjacent columns as is required by the input. This can be only achieved using VBA. A formula-only solution will not work (unless you're willing to create some really fancy formulas and just copy them to all adjacent columns showing `""` when not needed).

Comment: what if the number of boxes never gets bigger than 6 (6 columns)

Comment: Same answer: it can be done with formulas only but VBA would be easier / preferable. Either way: you'll have to come up with your own solution. My guess it that nobody here will write such a complex solution for you without any attempt from your side to solve it yourself. This is especially the case because (almost) every cell in this resulting array of cells will require a different formula (based on the adjacent cells and their values). I'd suggest you get started and once you get to the formula in cell `D4` (in the above example) you come back here and post your attempt to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your input:

[image]

Then the following will print "6" in the console:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rngA        As Range
    Dim units       As Long

    units = 22
    Set rngA = Range("A1")
    Debug.Print RoundUp(Split(rngA, ":")(1) / units)


End Sub

Public Function RoundUp(val As Double) As Double

    If (val - Int(val)) <> 0 Then
        RoundUp = Round(val + 0.5)
    Else
        RoundUp = val
    End If

End Function
```

The "magic" comes from the `RoundUp` function, that adds 0.5 to the value if it is not integer and thus ensures the rounding up.